# How can i use 'microsoft_graph' gem (ruby on rails) with a pre-saved access_token string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In a Ruby-on-Rails project, I'm trying to use the `microsoft_graph` gem to make Microsoft graph-ql requests (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby).
I want to initialize the client using a pre-saved access token to authenticate requests because there is already an Oauth flow to get users' access tokens for "offline" use.

I didn't find how to do this on the documentation

The documentation says use the following steps to instantiate the client but nothing seems to accept a ready-to-use access token string

```
context = MicrosoftKiotaAuthenticationOAuth::ClientCredentialContext.new("<the tenant id from your app registration>", "<the client id from your app registration>", "<the client secret from your app registration>")

authentication_provider = MicrosoftGraphCore::Authentication::OAuthAuthenticationProvider.new(context, nil, ["Files.Read"])

adapter = MicrosoftGraph::GraphRequestAdapter.new(authentication_provider)
client = MicrosoftGraph::GraphServiceClient.new(adapter)
```

What I want to achieve is something like the following code :

```
my_access_token = 'xxxx' 
client = MicrosoftGraph::GraphServiceClient.new(....) # get client that uses my access token to authenticate

client.me.select(....)
```

Comment: Looks like it might not be implemented yet. https://github.com/microsoft/kiota/issues/393

Comment: There are some known limitations: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby-core/issues/1